# Can I use `id` attribute with Perl's `CGI::radio_group`?

Tags: html, perl, cgi, radio-group

Kind of simple question:

Is there a way to use the `id` attribute for a radio group created with Perl's `CGI::radio_group` correctly?

When I tried it, each `<input>` element got the same ID, which most likely is not correct according to the example given in [`<input type="radio">` - HTML: HyperText Markup Language | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio).

Comment: The HTML generation functions in CGI.pm are very, very old. They come from a time when IDs were not really a thing yet. It doesn't look like what you want to do is possible from skimming the code, unfortunately. Development on the HTML generation has been stopped for years now, and the documentation strongly suggests not to use it.

Comment: I know, but maybe there should be words of warning in the documentation about it. Of course it could be fixed, too ;-)

Comment: The documentation covers what's possible, but it can never cover all the things that are not possible. You'd have to specifically give a different ID for every radio button element in this case. That is not in the docs. The only thing covered is to have shared additional attributes that get assigned to all of them. This make sense from an HTML 3 perspective. The CGI.pm module is only being maintained for security problems, so don't expect any changes to documentation unfortunately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please don't use the HTML generation functions from CGI.pm. We've known they are a terrible idea for at least 20 years. The [current documentation for CGI.pm](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI#HTML-Generation-functions-should-no-longer-be-used) contains this text:

> **HTML Generation functions should no longer be used**
>
> **All** HTML generation functions within CGI.pm are no longer being maintained. Any issues, bugs, or patches will be rejected unless they relate to fundamentally broken page rendering.
>
> The rationale for this is that the HTML generation functions of CGI.pm are an obfuscation at best and a maintenance nightmare at worst. You should be using a template engine for better separation of concerns. See [CGI::Alternatives](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Alternatives) for an example of using CGI.pm with the [Template::Toolkit](https://metacpan.org/pod/Template::Toolkit) module.
>
> These functions, and perldoc for them, are considered deprecated, they are no longer being maintained and no fixes or features for them will be accepted. They will, however, continue to exist in CGI.pm without any deprecation warnings ("soft" deprecation) so you can continue to use them if you really want to. All documentation for these functions has been moved to [CGI::HTML::Functions](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/CGI/lib/CGI/HTML/Functions.pod).

Really, they are a terrible idea. Using them will make your life harder than it needs to be. Putting real HTML in a template file is a far better idea.

Having said that, if you insist on doing the wrong thing, you can use the optional `-attribute` parameter to the `radio_group()` function (as documented in [`CGI::HTML::Functions(3pm)` for `radio_group()`](https://metacpan.org/dist/CGI/view/lib/CGI/HTML/Functions.pod#Creating-a-radio-button-group)). It takes a hash reference. The keys in hash are the values of the radio buttons and the associated values are references to other hashes that map attribute names onto values.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use CGI 'radio_group';

my @radios = qw[foo bar baz];
my %attributes = (
  foo => { id => 'FOO' },
  bar => { id => 'BAR' },
  baz => { id => 'BAZ' },
);

say radio_group(
  -name       => 'radio',
  -values     => \@radios,
  -attributes => \%attributes,
);
```

This produces the following HTML (when tidied up a bit):

```
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="radio" value="foo" checked="checked"  id="FOO"/>foo
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="radio" value="bar"  id="BAR"/>bar
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="radio" value="baz"  id="BAZ"/>baz
</label>
```

Did I make it clear enough that you shouldn't do this?

Comment: I had read that comment in the manual page, too. However templates are not always a better solution; specifically if you create structures with variable depth. Maybe also I did not grasp the full power of templates yet, but I feel that they make sense if you fill *some data* in an existing template, but less if more than 90% of the output structure is data-driven.

Comment: OK, where is that "attribute hash thing" documented? I see two alternatives when not being able (or wanting) to use templates: Use the existing old CGI code or start writing some new code, just covering my needs. I'd prefer to use the existing code as far as possible.

Comment: Good spot, I am surprised that works. I tried it after reading the source, and couldn't get it to work, but I didn't keep the code I used at the time.

Comment: @U.Windl: *OK, where is that "attribute hash thing" documented?* It's in the section of the documentation about [Creating a radio button group](https://metacpan.org/dist/CGI/view/lib/CGI/HTML/Functions.pod#Creating-a-radio-button-group) - "The optional **-attributes** argument is provided to assign any of the common HTML attributes to an individual menu item."

Comment: @DaveCross The program in question was started in 1998. Why should I dump a working program? I just discovered the duplicate ID problem recently when debugging the output. No browser had complained so far. I also drive a car that is 25 years old; even if it's 2022. Not convinced that "newer" is always "better" ;-)

Comment: @U.Windl: I'm not saying you should dump a working program - just suggesting that you should consider bringing it a bit more up-to-date. But, obviously, it's up to you whether or not you take the advice. And I never claimed that newer is always better - but in this case, it certainly is.